# Reset/swap two fragments in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, tabs, android-viewpager

I have two fragments in my `ViewPager` along with tabs. I have a settings option in my app which allows the user to choose the default fragment in the ViewPager.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 btnSaveLayout.Click += delegate
                {
                    var selectedId = radioGroupLayout.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                    radioButtonLayout = dialog.FindViewById<RadioButton>(selectedId);
                    layoutPreference = radioButtonLayout.Text;

                    mEditor.PutString("DefaultLayout", layoutPreference);
                    mEditor.Commit();
                    dialog.Dismiss();

                    SetupViewPager(layoutPreference); ;


                };



 private void SetupViewPager(string layoutPref)
            {

                adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
                pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.tabanim_viewpager);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(layoutPref) || layoutPref.Equals("First View"))
                {

                    adapter.AddFrag(new FirstFragment(), "First");
                    adapter.AddFrag(new SecondListFragment(), "List");

                }
                else
                {
                    adapter.AddFrag(new SecondListFragment(), "List");
                    adapter.AddFrag(new FirstFragment(), "First");

                }
                pager.Adapter = null;
                pager.Adapter = adapter;
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                tabLayout.SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.Aqua);
                tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(pager);

            }
```

With this , the tabs are changed but the fragments remain the same ie. the titles of the tabs change but the views associated to them remain the same. How can I solve this?

Any help is appreciated.